# How to make the new touched or selected item border visible and the previously selected/touched item border invisible in recyclerview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: show border of selected item]

This is what I want to achieve. Left Item is Selected and right one is not-selected. When I select the right one, then the right one should show border and left one shouldn't. Root of Single Item is MaterialCardView.

Answer (score 0):

Make a drawable with border. When user click on cardview1 then set its background with bordered drawable and set cardview2 background with null background and vice versa.
below is sample of drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#D0CFCC" /> 
  <solid android:color="#F8F7F5" /> 
  <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```